# How to perfectly merge two images and keep only the masked part

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, alpha

I have 2 images, image 1 contains a person and a background, image 2 contains a white silhouette of a person on a black background. I need to merge image 1 and image 2, keep only the person and save it as a PNG file without any jagged edges. How can I do this in android？Thanks

image1：

[image: image1]

image2:

[image: image2]

I use java code to apply the mask

```
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(alpha.getWidth(), alpha.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
    float value = 2f;
    float brightness = 255 * 100 / 100 * (1f - value);
    colorMatrix.set(new float[]{
            value, 0, 0, 0, brightness,
            0, value, 0, 0, brightness,
            0, 0, value, 0, brightness,
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0});
    paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix));
    canvas.drawBitmap(alpha, 0, 0, paint);

    int width = front.getWidth();
    int height = front.getHeight();
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    int[] frontPixels = new int[width * height];
    int[] alphaPixels = new int[width * height];
    int[] resultPixels = new int[width * height];
    front.getPixels(frontPixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    bitmap.getPixels(alphaPixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    int index = 0;

    //逐个像素赋值（这种写法比较耗时，后续可以优化）
    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
            index = width * row + col;
            if (alphaPixels[index] == Color.BLACK) {
                resultPixels[index] = Color.TRANSPARENT;
            } else {
                resultPixels[index] = frontPixels[index];
            }
        }
    }
    result.setPixels(resultPixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
```

and the result is:

[image: result]

I want the result is:

[image: no bg]

**I need to ensure that the output image has smooth edges and is free of jagged edges.**

Comment: Are the edges of your mask smooth enough?

Comment: Your mask is not binary, it has some gradients at the contour border. Opencv uses binary masks. If you want to blend in the gradient region, you can convert img and mask to float and multiply the 0-to-1 scaled mask with the image channels and convert back.

Comment: this task amounts to merging the (grayscale) mask as an alpha channel to the RGB data, and then dealing with issues around the edges, where pixels contain a mixture of background and foreground (requires estimating the background to calculate foreground). are you saying that's the task? -- if you don't require perfection, this is even easier. how much perfection do you require and why? most people don't have the perceptual acuity, optically and mentally, to tell how bad the usual methods are.

Comment: here's a rabbit hole https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XobSAXZaKJ8

Comment: @Micka not enough smooth

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz the result image has no background, the problem is make the edges smooth

Comment: Can you show the result applying the mask as it is? Maybe you only have to get rid of the gradient, for example with mask = mask > 254

Comment: @Micka hi, i have show the real result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd do in Desktop (not Android), using AWT BufferedImage, it might be easy to port to Android using Bitmap:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ImageMasker {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    if (args.length < 6) {
      System.out.println("Usage: \tjava ImageMaker -i image.jpg -m mask.jpg -o output.png \n\t[optional -b samesizebackgroundtarget.jpg / -t to use transparent, if -b is set it won't apply]");
      return;
    }

    String frontImagePath = null;
    String alphaMaskPath = null;
        String backgroundPath = null;
    String outputPath = null;
    boolean transparent = false;
    
        for (int i = 0;i < args.length; i++) {      
            if (args[i].equals("-i") && i < args.length - 1) {
                frontImagePath = args[i + 1];
                i++;
            }
            else if (args[i].equals("-m") && i < args.length - 1) {
                alphaMaskPath = args[i + 1];
            }
            else if (args[i].equals("-b") && i < args.length - 1) {
                backgroundPath = args[i + 1];
            }
            else if (args[i].equals("-o") && i < args.length - 1) {
                outputPath = args[i + 1];
            }
            else if (args[i].equals("-t")) {
                transparent = true;
            }
        }
        
        if (frontImagePath == null || alphaMaskPath == null || outputPath == null ){
            System.out.println("At least provide input, mask and outputh paths for image files");
            System.exit(0);
        }           

    BufferedImage frontImage = ImageIO.read(new File(frontImagePath));
    BufferedImage alphaMask = ImageIO.read(new File(alphaMaskPath));

    int width = frontImage.getWidth();
    int height = frontImage.getHeight();
    BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        
        // if -b background image to combine with is set
        BufferedImage bgImage = null;       
        if (backgroundPath != null) {
            bgImage = ImageIO.read(new File(backgroundPath));
            // ignore if dimensions are different
            if (width == bgImage.getWidth() || height == bgImage.getHeight()){
                transparent = false;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Background image to combine with is not of the same input dimensions... ignored!\n");
                backgroundPath = null;
            }           
        }
   
    // Process pixel by pixel, applying the mask as alpha channel or blending to a white background color
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        int frontPixel = frontImage.getRGB(x, y);
        int maskPixel = alphaMask.getRGB(x, y) & 0xff;
        int alphaValue = (int)(((float)maskPixel / 255.0f) * 255.0f);
        if(transparent){
          int resultPixel = (frontPixel & 0xffffff) | (alphaValue << 24);
          result.setRGB(x, y, resultPixel);
        }else {          
          int r = (frontPixel >> 16) & 0xff;
          int g = (frontPixel >> 8) & 0xff;
          int b = (frontPixel) & 0xff;
          float factor = alphaValue / 255.0f;
                    int bgR = 255; int bgG = 255; int bgB = 255; // white background hardcoded
                    // you can even use any other color (RGB) as background color                   
                    if (backgroundPath != null) {
                        // this will use the -b backgroundPath image give as background
                        int bgPixel = bgImage.getRGB(x, y);
                        bgR = (bgPixel >> 16) & 0xff;
                        bgG = (bgPixel >> 8) & 0xff;
                        bgB = (bgPixel) & 0xff;
                    }                   
          r = (int) (r * factor + bgR * (1 - factor));
          g = (int) (g * factor + bgG * (1 - factor));
          b = (int) (b * factor + bgB * (1 - factor));
          int solidPixel = (255 << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
          result.setRGB(x, y, solidPixel);
        }
      }
    }

    // Write the result image to a file
    File outputFile = new File(outputPath);
    ImageIO.write(result, "png", outputFile);
    
    System.out.println("Done!");
  }
}
```

Output samples: Solid white background color
[image: solid white]

Output samples: Transparent PNG
[image: Transparent background png]

Output samples: Combined with other picture as background
[image: Combined to another background image]

Output samples: Or even another color
[image: colored background]

I think this is how it should go on Android APIs for Bitmap handling (I haven't tested), assume it as a pseudocode:

```java
// Create the result Bitmap with the same dimensions as the frontImage
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(frontImage.getWidth(), frontImage.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

// Process pixel by pixel, applying the mask as alpha channel or blending to a white background color
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    int frontPixel = frontImage.getPixel(x, y);
    int maskPixel = alphaMask.getPixel(x, y) & 0xff;
    int alphaValue = (int)(((float)maskPixel / 255.0f) * 255.0f);
    if(transparent){
      int resultPixel = (frontPixel & 0xffffff) | (alphaValue << 24);
      result.setPixel(x, y, resultPixel);
    }else {          
      int r = (frontPixel >> 16) & 0xff;
      int g = (frontPixel >> 8) & 0xff;
      int b = (frontPixel) & 0xff;
      float factor = alphaValue / 255.0f;
      int bgR = 255; int bgG = 255; int bgB = 255; 
      if (backgroundPath != null) { // is using another image as background
        int bgPixel = bgImage.getPixel(x, y);
        bgR = (bgPixel >> 16) & 0xff;
        bgG = (bgPixel >> 8) & 0xff;
        bgB = (bgPixel) & 0xff;
      }          
      r = (int) (r * factor + bgR * (1 - factor));
      g = (int) (g * factor + bgG * (1 - factor));
      b = (int) (b * factor + bgB * (1 - factor));
      int solidPixel = (255 << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
      result.setPixel(x, y, solidPixel);
    }
  }
}
```